# java: how to check the type of an ArrayList as a whole

Tags: java, arraylist

i know how to hard code an algorithm on how to check the types of each object in an arraylist, but is there any other way in checking the type of that ArrayList<> in one go, i mean my application has only three types of arraylist. Say i have a function that returns an ArrayList, and its definiton is that in a variable o (its an arraylist of object ofcourse) i'll add a person object,

```
o.add(person);
```

and having added all person data on an arraylist of objects and when a call this function say the name of my function is getData(),

```
ArrayList <Object> obj = getData();
```

so i know that in that ArrayList that i returned from calling getData() that it is all person object, how do i know the type of that ArrayList?.

Just wanted that function to be more generic in sense, this is for my application though, geniric troughout my application.

Is there any other way of doing this, i can think of an algorithm but is there any short cut or easy way of doing this?..

Comment: @codesparcle what you mean under "will not compile"?

Comment: ouch. thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I think the class in question is java.util.ArrayList @codesparkle and that support generics.

Comment: absolutely, I was momentarily confused, sorry.

Comment: @codesparkle, take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: The type of the ArrayList is an `ArrayList` at runtime.  The generic type is a compile time feature.

Comment: Do you mean the type of the elements in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @all yes, i mean the type of elements and checking them in one go, like not checking each of the objects in that arraylist but by just one call of a function or what,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'the type' of an `ArrayList`.

The class `ArrayList` stores a list of `Object` references. It doesn't know and doesn't care if they are all of some type.

The Java generic system adds **compile-time** checking to help you keep track of types. So, if you declare `ArrayList<Person>`, you will get compile errors if you write code that could insert a non-`Person` into your list.

At runtime, the only way to tell what is in an `ArrayList` to iterate over all the contained items and check them with `instanceof`.

Comment: hmmm i got your point, so there is no way to really lessen the code lines checking the arraylist elements in one go, i mean i have to hardcode an algorithm to check each element :D gonna accept this answer a little while, maybe there are guys who knows a much simplier way :D

Comment: after exhausting all efforts got nothing but this one, hehehe have to manually check each element and convert it to a specifide type of objects in an arraylist.. this one is the best bet for those who want an easy way of checking types in arraylist

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is a way without casting every item manually(it still is ugly though..)

```
//start with an arraylist of unknown generic type
ArrayList <Object> obj = getData();

//Make an array from it(basically the same as looping over the list
// and casting it to the real type of the list entries)
Object[] objArr = obj.toArray();

//Check if the array is not empty and if the componentType of the 
//array can hold an instance of the class Person 
if(objArr.length>0 
    && objArr.getClass().getComponentType().isAssignableFrom(Person.class)) {
    // do sth....
}
```

This should not give any unchecked warnings.

You could use it like this:

```
private boolean isArrayOfType(Object[] array,Class<?> aClass) {
    return array.length > 0
            && array.getClass().getComponentType().isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}
Object[] personArr = getData().toArray();
if(isArrayOfType(personArr,Person.class) {
   //Do anything...

}
```

What won't work is the following:

```
// -> This won't work, sry!
       ArrayList<Person> personArrayList = Arrays.asList((Person[])personArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the list is not empty, get the first element:

```
type = this.list.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName();
```